# Given a string, Return its Cumulative Delta

Tags: code-golf, string, number, arithmetic, array

*[Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/94519/output-a-strings-cumulative-slope)*

## Explanation

Given a string such as `DCBA`, convert it to ASCII ordinals, such as `68 67 66 65`. Then, take the differences between each value, eg `67 - 68 = -1, 66 - 67 = -1...` giving `-1 -1 -1` Now as long as there is more than 1 left over value, repeat getting the differences.

For a 3 letter string, your pathway should be similar to

```
A   F   G
65  70  71
-5  -1
-4
```

And for a 5 letter string...

```
B   A   C   E   D   F
66  65  67  69  68  70
1   -2  -2  1   -2
3   0   -3  3
3   3   -6
0   9
-9
```

## The Challenge

Take a string input through any [Standard IO Method](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), and output the value of the cumulative delta as described above.

## Test Cases

```
input: cows
output: 8

input: helloworld
output: 905

input: aaaaaa
output: 0

input: abcdef
output: 0

input: ghfie
output: 20

input: CODEGOLF
output: 185
```

## Rules

- [Standard Loopholes Apply](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- The input will only consist of ASCII letters that are either all uppercase or all lowercase
- Your code MUST work for both lower and upper case.
- The input will contain at least 2 characters.
- The output may be positive or negative, as long as its absolute value matches the absolute value of the cumulative delta.
- This is marked as [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), as such, shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: What is the expected output for a single character input? Or is a single-character input even valid?

Comment: @Suever Presumably just the character's ordinal.

Comment: @Suever Behaviour undefined. I'll add a note under rules that a single character input will not be supplied. (Although the character's ordinal is what was outputted by my test code)

Comment: Negatives would matter in all the intermediate steps, so I'm not sure why you'd want to ignore them in the final output.

Comment: @Geobits If the string was taken in reverse, "FA" or "AF", the difference in the end cumulative delta is simply signage, "5" or "-5" respectively. The same applies for strings of any length. I've shown no biased for signage purely due to the fact that some languages consider deltas in different orders to others, to make the challenge slightly easier.

Comment: @nimi fixed, was the result of bad planning on my behalf

Comment: Once again, Signage of the output does not matter. -185 = 185 for the sake of this question.

Comment: how do i post my solution...i come with an equation to solve this question.(using pascal triangle)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

-2 bytes thanks to @Dennis (implement a while loop)

```
OIṖ¿
```

**[TryItOnline](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=T0nhuZbCvw&input=&args=ImhlbGxvd29ybGQi)**
[RunAllTestCases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=T0nhuZbCvwrFvMOH4oKsWeKCrFk&input=&args=Wydjb3dzJywnaGVsbG93b3JsZCcsJ2FhYWFhYScsJ2FiY2RlZicsJ2doZmllJywnQ09ERUdPTEYnXQ)

#### How?

```
OIṖ¿ - Main link: s
O     - cast to ordinals
  Ṗ¿  - while, ¿, pop last value, Ṗ, evaluates to True:
 I    -     find increments between consecutive values
```

Comment: You can save two bytes with `¿` (while loop).

Comment: @Dennis - I can never make while loops...

Comment: `OIṖ¿` does the job here.

Comment: Huh the condition is pop?

Comment: Yes. Once there's a single digit left, `Ṗ` will return an empty array, breaking out of the loop. The condition doesn't affect the return value.

Answer (score 9):

## Python 3, 71 bytes

```python
s=input();k=r=0
for c in s:r=ord(c)-r*k/(len(s)-k);k+=1
print(round(r))
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/QIbBwz).

#### Alternate version, 58 bytes (inexact)

If an approximate result is enough – e.g., **-904.9999999999993 ≈ -905** for input **helloworld** – then the following solution works as well.

```python
f=lambda s,k=1:len(s)and-~-len(s)*f(s[1:],k+1)/k+ord(s[0])
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/y6QJQf).

#### Background

**Proposition** *Let* **f** *be a variadic function that maps the code points* **s<sub>0</sub>, ⋯, s<sub>n</sub>** *to their cumulative delta with sign* **(-1)<sup>n</sup>**, i.e.,

[image: definition]

*Then*

[image: proposition]

**Proof** The statement is clearly true when **n = 0**. Suppose that it holds for **n - 1**, where **n > 0**.

By the recursive definition of **f** and the hypothesis,

[image: proof]

By induction, the statement holds for all non-negative values of **n**.

#### How it works

Since

[image: nCr]

we can rewrite the proposition as follows.

[image: formula]

The iterative implementation does precisely this. Numerators are computed by incrementing **k**, denominators by subtracting **k** from the length of the input string **s**, i.e., **n+1**.

Unfortunately, not all fractions will evaluate to integers, so the result is computed using floating point arithmetic and finally rounded to the nearest integer.

The recursive implementation does roughly the same, but it keeps track of the denominator via the auxiliary variable **k** and computes the numerator by subtracting **1** from the length of the remaining string (`~-len(s)`).

Comment: The explanation currently has some bugs (mostly related to signs). I'll fix that asap.

Answer (score 7):

## MATL, 5 bytes

```
`dtnq
```

[**Try it Online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YGR0bnE&input=J2hlbGxvd29ybGQn) or here is a slightly modified version for [all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YApgZHRucQpdRFQ&input=J2Nvd3MnCidoZWxsb3dvcmxkJwonYWFhYWFhJwonYWJjZGVmJwonZ2hmaWUnCidDT0RFR09MRic).

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab the input as a string
`       % Do....while loop
    d   % Compute the difference between all consecutive ASCII codes
    tnq % Determine the current length and subtract 1
        % Implicit end of do...while. Evaluate (and consume) stack element and break out
        % of loop if it's 0.
        % Implicit end of loop and display
```

Comment: Gosh Darn MATL.
...Have an explanation?

Comment: @JonathanAllan As stated in the challenge, sign doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

## J, 15 bytes

```
<:@#2&(-/\)3&u:
```

### Usage

```
   f =: <:@#2&(-/\)3&u:
   f 'cows'
8
   f 'helloworld'
_905
   f 'aaaaaa'
0
   f 'abcdef'
0
   f 'ghfie'
_20
   f 'CODEGOLF'
_185
```

### Explanation

```
<:@#2&(-/\)3&u:  Input: string S
           3&u:  Ordinal of each char
   #             Get the length of S
<:@                Decrement it
    2&(   )      Repeat len(s)-1 times on x = ordinal(S)
    2    \         For each pair of values
       -/            Reduce using subtraction
                   Return that as the next value of x
                 Return the final x as the result
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>80</s> 73 bytes

Saving 7 bytes thanks to Dennis.

```python
L=map(ord,input())
while L[1:]:L=[x-y for x,y in zip(L,L[1:])]
print L[0]
```

Requires input to be given in quotes, e.g. `"helloworld"`

Comment: You can replace `raw_input` with `input` if you surround the string with quotes ([allowed by default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7634/12012)). Also, `len(L)>1` can become `L[1:]`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
ÇDgG¥}`
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4dEZ0fCpX1g&input=aGVsbG93b3JsZA)

**Explanation**

```
Ç        # convert to list of ascii codes
 DgG }   # length-1 times do:
    ¥    # take deltas
      `  # pop the single value left in the list and output
```

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 147 bytes

```
(let p((l(map char->integer(string->list s))))(if(= 1(length l))(car l)(p
(for/list((i(range 1(length l))))(-(list-ref l(- i 1))(list-ref l i))))))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define (f s)
  (let loop ((lst (map char->integer (string->list s))))
    (if (= 1 (length lst))
        (first lst)
        (loop (for/list ((i (range 1 (length lst))))
                (- (list-ref lst (sub1 i)) 
                   (list-ref lst i))
                )))))
```

Testing:

```
(f "AFG")
(f "BACEDF")
(f "cows")
(f "helloworld")
(f "abcdef")
(f "aaaaaa")
(f "ghfie")
(f "CODEGOLF")
```

Output:

```
-4
-9
8
-905
0
0
-20
-185
```

Comment: Signage doesn't matter for the answer. You can save those characters.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will remove absolute function.

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 17 Bytes

```
►Sb]L1-1\1:[d}P
```

### Explination

```
►                   # Spaceless segment
 Sb                 # Convert the input to a stack, convert the stack of strings to a stack of ordinals.
   ]L               # Push a duplicate of that stack, pop it and push the length in its place
     1-             # Subtract 1 from the length.
       1\1          # Push a one, slide it under the top value, push another one, such that 1 LENGTH 1
          :  }      # For (i=1; i<=LENGTH; i+=1)
           [d       # Pop the iterator, pop the current stack, push the delta stack representing it.
              P     # Pop the top value of the stack, push it to the reg stack, and implicitly print.
```

I used (A version of) this script to test the question itself. I thought I might as well share it.

[Try It Online!](https://tehflamintaco.github.io/Reverse-Programmer-Notation/RProgN.html?rpn=%E2%96%BASb%5DL1-1%5C1%3A%5Bd%7D%2B&input=cows)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>51</s> 47 bytes

```
g[x]=x
g x=g$zipWith(-)=<<tail$x
g.map fromEnum
```

Usage example: `g.map fromEnum $ "CODEGOLF"`-> `185`.

`map fromEnum` turns the string into a list of ascii values. If it has only a single element, return it, else build neighbor differences and check again.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 116 bytes

Good that the input is more than 1 char so I can use `s.length` for both Arrays and Strings!

Snippet referenced from [Neil's answer on another question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96085/59806) :P

```js
d=k=>/\d/.test(k)?k:k.charCodeAt(0);r=x=>(a=[...x],a.pop(),a.map((c,i)=>d(c)-d(x[i+1])));f=s=>s.length-1?f(r(s)):s[0]
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=this.value&&f(this.value)><pre id=o>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 97 bytes

```
([][()]<>){<>([][()]){({}[()]<({}[({})]<>)><>)}{}{}<>([]){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}<>({}<>[()])}<>
```

[Try it online!](http://brain-flak.tryitonline.net/#code=KFtdWygpXTw-KXs8PihbXVsoKV0peyh7fVsoKV08KHt9Wyh7fSldPD4pPjw-KX17fXt9PD4oW10peyh7fVsoKV08KHt9PD4pPD4-KX17fTw-KHt9PD5bKCldKX08Pg&input=Y293cw&args=LWE)

This is 97 bytes of code, plus 3 bytes for the `-a` flag, which enables ASCII input.

This would be a lot simpler if we didn't have to worry about the difference between characters sometimes being zero. Instead, we have to muck around with reversing the stack and pushing stack height several times.

Explanation:

```
Push the stack height onto the alternate stack
([][()]<>)

While this stack is non-empty:
{

    Move back
    <>

    Push the height of the stack minus one
    ([][()])

    While true
    {

        Decrement the stack height counter
        ({}[()]

        Move the difference over to the other stack
        <({}[({})]<>)><>)

    }

    Pop the last value and the left-over counter
    {}{}

    Move on to the other stack
    <>

    Move everything back
    ([]){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}

    Pop the counter
    {}<>

    Move the step number minus one back
    ({}<>[()])

End
}

Move back one last time
<>
```

Answer (score 0):

### R, 58 bytes

```
x=rev(utf8ToInt(readline()));while(length(x)>1)x=diff(x);x
```

`diff()` in R works differently than the difference defined in this challenge. Therfore we have reverse the vector (using `rev`) prior to taking the difference the first time.